# Angular ng-repeat $index

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I'm creating a list of items the user can click to go to the next picture.

```
<ol class="indicators">
<li ng-repeat="img in pics" ng-click="slideTo($index)"></li>
</ol>
```

this code works but the problem is that it doesnt fill in the $index in the ngClick directive. This is the resulting html:

```
<li ng-repeat="img in pics" ng-click="slideTo($index)" class="ng-scope"></li>
```

if I put the $index in between {{ }}, it does work, but I get an error in the console.

*Resulting html:*

```
<li ng-repeat="img in pics" ng-click="slideTo(0)" class="ng-scope"></li>
```

*Error:*

> Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=10&p3=slideTo(%7B%7BNaNndex%7D%7D)&p4=%7B%index%7D%7D

I've seen examples of this where they dont use the curly brackets but then the $index was used in a child element and not the element itself.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and when you should use {{ }} when using Angular Expressions.

Comment: Your first example should fill it in...how do you know it doesnt? Does that click event not work, or does your inspector show it not filled in?

Comment: Use track by $index in ng-repeat <li ng-repeat="img in pics track by $index" ng-click="slideTo($index)></li>

Comment: @tymeJV my inspector shows it not filled in.

Comment: Because ng-repeat takes an expression and using `{{` makes an invalid expression. `{{` is called interpolation. Do you have a simple demo to showcase the issue without interpolation

Comment: @ParthipanS I've tried track by, but it doesnt change anything...

Comment: can you show your issue in jsfiddle

Comment: You are missing the close quote on the `ng-click`, is that just a typo or is that missing in the real code too?

Comment: So even though your inspector shows it not filled, does it work?

Comment: why do you need to fill it? thats not how angular works

Comment: Should work, see [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vadiqeqari/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks! Even though its not filled in in my inspector, it does seem to work! :) I wanted to code step by  step as this is my first Angular project and thought I did something wrong because it didnt change the ng-click attribute... But apparently thats how Angular works! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspector will not show it filled in, however, if you try logging the parameter passed to the function you will see that it is indeed the corresponding index number to the item you clicked on.